# Communicate between a python server and node server

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs

I have an application that uses two servers that need to communicate with one another. One is a python server that implements BaseHTTPRequestHandler's do_METHODs. The other is node js's development server/production server that hosts a React JS application.

The node js application uses a POST request to get a message from an input which the python server extracts that message from that POST request and then calls Amazon's Lex using Boto3 to get a response.

Whenever I run node js development server (on localhost:3000) and the python server (on localhost:3001), the python server is able to recognize that a POST request has been made and goes ahead and gets a response. However, when I run node js production server (on localhost:5000) and the python server (on localhost:3001), the node js server is unable to communicate with the python server. Why is this?

Comment: Did you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you changed port in wrong places. Better show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I felt like having two local applications running on different ports is a little impractical or rather more complicated than it should be.

As such, I have migrated my project to use Django instead of using React JS and integrate it with python. This way Django's back-end can handle the POST requests I make and update the DOM as needed.

All this is for a chatbot application that is suppose take a user's question, call Amazon's Lex for a intent and entity which then spaCy, a ML framework, searches our database for an answer. The answer is then returned and the DOM is then updated without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between a local development server and any other server on the internet, you will need to tunnel your connection.  By default, routers are configured to deny all incoming traffic, so when your node instance tries to communicate with your dev server, it doesn't pass the firewall.

An easy solution is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).  Once you have it installed, open a new terminal window and run:

```
 ngrok http <PORT>
```

where `<PORT>` is 3001, since that is the port your dev server is listening on.

This answer is assuming that you are actually running your node.js instance on a production server, and not on your local computer.  If that isn't the case then this probably won't fix your problem.